# input table 1 (5 6 7) (Five Six Seven) and table 2 (5 6 7 ). Both in brackets are columns with values.,I want to get the five for the 5 in table2

Tags: sql, oracle

table 1

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | five |
| 6 | six |
| 8 | eight |

table 2
5|6|5
6|5
8|8|5

Expected output
|five|six|five|
|six|five|
|eight|eight|five|

Comment: SQL table is not a spreadsheet. You cannot "vertically align" two tables without explicit row number

Answer (score 0):

That "link" you're talking about is called a **join**.

As you put it, that would be as follows:

Sample data (you already have that and don't type it):

```
SQL> with
  2  table_1 (col1, col2) as
  3    (select 5, 'five'  from dual union all
  4     select 6, 'six'   from dual union all
  5     select 8, 'eight' from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_2 (col1) as
  8    (select 5  from dual union all
  9     select 6  from dual union all
 10     select 8  from dual
 11    )
 12  --
```

Query begins here:

```
 13  select b.col1
 14  from table_1 a join table_2 b on a.col1 = b.col1
 15  where a.col2 = '&par_col2';
Enter value for par_col2: five

      COL1
----------
         5

SQL> /
Enter value for par_col2: eight

      COL1
----------
         8

SQL>
```

---

Depending on a tool you use, `where` clause might use a bind variable instead of a substitution one (I used in SQL*Plus), i.e.

```
where a.col2 = :par_col2
```

---

On the other hand, what do you need `table_2` for? Everything you need is contained in `table_1`, so query would then be just

```
<snip>
 13  select a.col1
 14  from table_1 a
 15  where a.col2 = '&par_col2';
Enter value for par_col2: six

      COL1
----------
         6

SQL>
```